# Utilizing value labels in custom wrapper function around dplyr::case_match() to go inside of dplyr::mutate() and dplyr::across()

Tags: r, dplyr, metadata, metaprogramming, nse

TL:DR- I would like to create a function that automates the process of creating a new column with values "Agree" or "Disagree" based on the underlying metadata (value labels) for the column undergoing the transformation. I would like this to be able operate inside of both `dplyr::across()` and `dplyr::mutate()`. Moreover, it needs two arguments, one for the variable/column that will be recoded and one for the data frame that is piped into `dplyr::mutate()`. I believe it needs the data frame so that it can access the underlying metadata of the column being operated on.

EDIT: I was able to create a much simpler function that works based on some of the code from @Mark.

```
# make data
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  3, 2, 3,
  4, 4, 2,
  2, 3, 1,
  1, 1, 4
) %>% 
  # add value labels
  labelled::set_value_labels(
    x = c(`Strongly agree` = 1, `Somewhat agree` = 2, `Somewhat disagree` = 3, `Strongly disagree` = 4),
    y = c(`Strongly agree` = 1, `Somewhat agree` = 2, `Somewhat disagree` = 3, `Strongly disagree` = 4),
    z = c(`Strongly agree` = 1, `Somewhat agree` = 2, `Somewhat disagree` = 3, `Strongly disagree` = 4)
  )

# write the function
make_dicho <- function(df = data, var) {
  var <- rlang::enexpr(var)
  if (!is.character(var)) {
    # convert to a sym() object and then use as_name to make it a string
    var <- rlang::as_name(rlang::ensym(var))
  }
  
  # conver the vector to a factor
  haven::as_factor(df[[var]]) %>% 
    # remove the first part of the factor
    stringr::str_extract("(?<=\\s).+") %>% 
    # make the first letter uppercase
    stringr::str_to_sentence()
}

# check that it outputs a vector
make_dicho(data, x)

# check that it works inside dplyr::mutate()
data %>% dplyr::mutate(new_x = make_dicho(., x))

# check that it works in dplyr::across()
data %>% mutate(
  across(
    c(x:z),
    \(var) make_dicho(., var),
    .names = "new_{col}"
  )
)
```

I am social scientist who works with survey data a lot. Many of the variables are four point agree-disagree likert scales with response options "Strongly agree", "Somewhat agree", "Somewhat disagree", "Strongly disagree", but sometimes are six point scales. A consistent part of the data cleaning process is to convert these variables into dichotomous factors (meaning they have two response options of "Agree" and Disagree"). Here is an example below where `data` is the data frame, `x` is the original variable with all four response options, and `new_x` is the dichotomized variable:

```r
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, labelled, rlang)

data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    new_x = dplyr::case_match(
      x,
      c(1:2) ~ "Agree",
      c(3:4) ~ "Disagree"
    )
  )
```

The issue is that I often have over 30+ variables that I have to do this with. I know that I can use `across()` to do this same data transformation over all 30 variables, but I have to repeat this every couple of weeks when we get new survey data back. Instead, I would like to have a function called something like `make_dicho()` that I can use inside of `mutate()` and `across()` so that I don't have to write the entire `case_match()` expression out every single time. Here is a successful attempt at building a rudimentary version:

```
# create sample data
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  3, 2, 3,
  4, 4, 2,
  2, 3, 1,
  1, 1, 4
)

df

# create the function where values of 1-2 are "Agree" and 3-4 are "Disagree"
make_dicho <- function(var) {
  dplyr::case_match(
    x,
    c(1:2) ~ "Agree",
    c(3:4) ~ "Disagree"
  )
}

# check to see if it worked
df %>% dplyr::mutate(new_x = make_dicho(x))

# success!
```

This function works, but it is very fragile as it relies on the survey designer and survey provider using four response options and coding the values in a very specific way. One way to avoid this is to leverage the underlying metadata which contains value labels that indicate what each value means. Since most of my data contains this metadata, I would like to use it to automatically decide which values should be recoded as "Agree" and which should be recoded as "Disagree". This complicates things significantly as I now need to add a new argument for the data frame. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
# add value labels to the data

data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  3, 2, 3,
  4, 4, 2,
  2, 3, 1,
  1, 1, 4
) %>% 
  # add value labels
  labelled::set_value_labels(
    x = c(`Strongly agree` = 1, `Somewhat agree` = 2, `Somewhat disagree` = 3, `Strongly disagree` = 4),
    y = c(`Strongly agree` = 1, `Somewhat agree` = 2, `Somewhat disagree` = 3, `Strongly disagree` = 4),
    z = c(`Strongly agree` = 1, `Somewhat agree` = 2, `Somewhat disagree` = 3, `Strongly disagree` = 4)
  )

# write the new function
make_dicho <- function(df = NULL, var) {

  ## if var is a symbol convert it to a string
  # "Returns a naked expression of the variable"
  var <- rlang::enexpr(var)
  
  if (!is.character(var)) {
    # convert to a sym() object and then use as_name to make it a string
   var <- rlang::as_name(rlang::ensym(var))
  }

  # Since this is taking advantage of labelled data, it should be of class haven_labelled 
  if (class(df[[var]])[1] == "haven_labelled") {

    ### Set up vectors based on the underlying attribute
    
    # get the named vector
    labs <- attributes(df[[var]])$labels
    
    
    # flip the names
    labs <- setNames(names(labs), labs)
    
    
    # get the agree vector by removing the strings containing "disagree" or "Disagree"
    agree_vec <- labs[!str_detect(labs, pattern = "disagree|Disagree")]
    
    # now flip the vector back and make it numeric
    # enframe() converts named atomic vectors or lists to one- or two-column data frames.
    agree_vec <- tibble::enframe(agree_vec) %>%
      # put the "value" column at the beginning of the df
      dplyr::relocate(value) %>%
      # convert "name" to numeric
      dplyr::mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
      # deframe() converts two-column data frames to a named vector or list
      tibble::deframe()
    
    
    # get the agree vector by keeping the strings containing "disagree" or "Disagree"
    disagree_vec <- labs[str_detect(labs, pattern = "disagree|Disagree")]
    
    # now flip the vector back and make it numeric
    # enframe() converts named atomic vectors or lists to one- or two-column data frames.
    disagree_vec <- tibble::enframe(disagree_vec) %>%
      # put the "value" column at the beginning of the df
      dplyr::relocate(value) %>%
      # convert "name" to numeric
      dplyr::mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
      # deframe() converts two-column data frames to a named vector or list
      tibble::deframe()
    
    
    
    ### now create the case_match function,
    # Adding in df[[var]] so that it know which vector to use
    dplyr::case_match(
      df[[var]],
      agree_vec ~ "Agree",
      disagree_vec ~ "Disagree"
    ) 
    
    }

}

# test function
data %>% dplyr::mutate(new_x = make_dicho(x))
```

This fails and gives an error that says `argument "var" is missing, with no default`. However, if I add `.` inside `make_dicho()` it works. Like this:

```
data %>% dplyr::mutate(new_x = make_dicho(., x))
```

My first question is, how do I update my function so that it no longer requires the `.` at the beginning? Secondly, how do I get it to work in `dplyr::across()`? Here is the code I used for `dplyr::across()`:

```
# make all three variables dichotomous factors with "new_" prefix
df %>% dplyr::mutate(
  dplyr::across(
    c(x:z),
    ~make_dicho(., .x),
    .names = "new_{col}"
  )
)
```

Here is the error image I am getting when I try using `across()`. My guess is that it has something to do with the `.` inside of the `make_dicho()` call and by the call to `df[[var]]` found in the `dplyr::case_match()`. But I honestly have no idea and, while it feels like I am very close, for all I know this function could be all messed up.

[image]

In sum, I would like to create a function that automates the process of creating a new column with values "Agree" or "Disagree" based on the underlying metadata for the column undergoing the transformation. I would like this to be able operate inside of both `dplyr::across()` and `dplyr::mutate()`. Moreover, it needs two arguments, one for the variable/column that will be recoded and one for the data frame that is piped into `dplyr::mutate()`. I believe it needs the data frame so that it can access the underlying metadata of the column being operated on.

Hopefully the request, while a bit complicated, is easy to understand. Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: there's a lot of information here but no desired output. Please include a desired output so you don't get (another) answer which isn't what you're looking for

Comment: I've added a desired output at the end of my request and at the beginning.

Comment: you actually haven't created a desired output. A desired output could be a dataframe, the expected result after transforming the example input. Think of it like in a recipe- you don't just get a description of the steps- a picture of what it's meant to look like at the end is super helpful for knowing if you did the right thing!

Comment: Ah do you mean the desired output of the function or like my overall desired output from posing the question? I think you mean the former but I originally thought you meant the latter. If it is the former, then I would like the function to create a character vector with values "Agree" or "Disagree" so that when used in dplyr::mutate() it creates a new column or updates an existing one. Is that what you mean by desired output?

Comment: I meant literally the vector which you had in mind for the dataframe `data`

Comment: words are fairly slippery, so it helps to have something to point to and say "make something which turns the input into this", I make something, and the example can be refined to get you closer to what you want

Comment: Totally makes sense! I just wanted to clarify exactly what you meant by output. I'll start doing that in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256819/discussion-between-jdenn0514-and-mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different questions you have posed, so to break it down:

> This [(`data %>% mutate(new_x = make_dicho(x))`)] fails and gives an error that says argument "var" is missing, with no default. However, if I add . inside make_dicho() it works

This is because make_dicho has two arguments, `df`, with the default value  `NULL`, and `var`. If you give only one argument, it will assume that it's the first one, `df`, hence the error.

> My first question is, how do I update my function so that it no longer requires the . at the beginning?

There's a few different ways:

1. Change `make_dicho <- function(df = NULL, var) {` to `make_dicho <- function(var, df = data) {`. This will obviously not work if the dataframe you're working with changes name
2. Make it something simpler, e.g. something like this:

```
data |> mutate(across(x:z, \(a) str_extract(names(val_labels(a))[a], "(?<=\\s).+"), .names = "new_{col}"))
# or 
make_dicho <- \(a) str_extract(names(val_labels(a))[a], "(?<=\\s).+")
data |> mutate(across(x:z, make_dicho, .names = "new_{col}"))
```

> Secondly, how do I get it to work in across()?[...] Here is the error image I am getting when I try using across(). My guess is that it has something to do with the . inside of the make_dicho() call and by the call to df[[var]] found in the case_match. But I honestly have no idea and, while it feels like I am very close, for all I know this function could be all messed up.

Your assumption is right- the problem is that in that format of anonymous function (i.e. `~ .x` etc.), you can use `.` instead. See:

```
data |> mutate(across(everything(), ~ ., .names = "new_{col}"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  x                     y                     z          new_x   new_y   new_z  
  <dbl+lbl>             <dbl+lbl>             <dbl+lbl>  <dbl+l> <dbl+l> <dbl+l>
1 3 [Somewhat disagree] 2 [Somewhat agree]    3 [Somewh… 3 [Som… 2 [Som… 3 [Som…
2 4 [Strongly disagree] 4 [Strongly disagree] 2 [Somewh… 4 [Str… 4 [Str… 2 [Som…
3 2 [Somewhat agree]    3 [Somewhat disagree] 1 [Strong… 2 [Som… 3 [Som… 1 [Str…
4 1 [Strongly agree]    1 [Strongly agree]    4 [Strong… 1 [Str… 1 [Str… 4 [Str…
```

The solution is to either define a function as a separate thing, or use the new `\(x) x` syntax, like so:

```
data %>% mutate(
  across(
    x:z,
    \(a) make_dicho(., a),
    .names = "new_{col}"
  )
)
```

Comment: This is actually super helpful, I really appreciate it. Two clarifying questions:
1. If I set it to `make_dicho <- function(var, df = data)` it would only work for when my data is called "data" right? At that point, since all of my data frames would need to be called "data", couldn't I just remove that from the function and put "data" everywhere "df" is located in the function?
2. The `\(x) x` syntax is basically setting an anonymous function right? If so, how does that fix the problem?

Comment: no worries! glad I could help! To answer your questions: 1. yeah, you are right, however, if say, you wanted it to usually be `data`, but have the option of, say, using it with another dataframe, then that option with the default is relatively good. 2. yes it's an anonymous function. The difference is that with `\(x) x`, only `x` is an input, `.x` doesn't mean anything, and `.` is the dataframe. `\(x) x` is equivalent to `function(x) x`

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks! I'll mark your answer as the correct one. I was originally hoping to not have to use an anonymous function and just have it ignore the `df` argument but this is more than adequate

Comment: @jdenn0514 you don't have to use an anonymous function - see `make_dicho <- \(a) str_extract(names(val_labels(a))[a], "(?<=\\s).+")`

Answer (score 0):

Not touching the methodology of survey evaluation, but simply considering
the intended coding, this could be one approach. You would still need to know the encoding of the individual variables and type them in the `.cols` with corresponding `make_dicho` arguments in `mutate(across(...))`.

```
library(tidyverse)

## create sample data
## let's say `up` refers to higher values indicate higher agreement, `down`
## indicates lower values indicate higher agreement. let's also introduce
## some "errors" you may be faced with (e.g., `NA`, unrealistic values).
dat <- tibble(
  sc6_up_x = c(1,4,5,2),
  sc6_down_x = c(2,5,1000,4),
  sc6_up_y = c(NA,6,1,6),
  sc4_down_x = c(3,4,2,1),
  sc4_down_y = c(2,4,3,1),
  sc4_up_x = c(3,2,1,4)
)

dat

# create function
make_dicho <- function(x_var, agr_l, agr_u, dis_l, dis_u) {
  dplyr::case_match(
    x_var,
    c(agr_l:agr_u) ~ "Agree",
    c(dis_l:dis_u) ~ "Disagree"
  )
}

## check to see if it works when using one variable
dat %>% 
  mutate(new_x = make_dicho(sc6_down_x, 1,3,4,6))

## apply function to several variables of interest and with appropriate
## arguments
dat %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = c(sc6_up_x, sc6_up_y),
      .fns = list(
        make_dicho = ~ make_dicho(.x,4,6,1,3)
      ),
      .names = "new_{col}"
    ),
    across(
      .cols = c(sc6_down_x),
      .fns = list(
        make_dicho = ~ make_dicho(.x,1,3,4,6)
      ),
      .names = "new_{col}"
    ),
    across(
      .cols = c(sc4_up_x),
      .fns = list(
        make_dicho = ~ make_dicho(.x,3,4,1,2)
      ),
      .names = "new_{col}"
    ),
    across(
      .cols = c(sc4_down_x, sc4_down_y),
      .fns = list(
        make_dicho = ~ make_dicho(.x,1,2,3,4)
      ),
      .names = "new_{col}"
    )
    )
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in base R.

Assuming that your data is as you've given it, let's first convert it back to base R: factor variables and data frame data:

```r
for (nn in names(data)) {
  data[,nn] %<>% to_factor
}
data %<>% as.data.frame
data
#>                   x                 y                 z
#> 1 Somewhat disagree    Somewhat agree Somewhat disagree
#> 2 Strongly disagree Strongly disagree    Somewhat agree
#> 3    Somewhat agree Somewhat disagree    Strongly agree
#> 4    Strongly agree    Strongly agree Strongly disagree
```

Now that your data is in base R format, all you need to do is rename the levels.

```r
nr = nrow(data)
for (nn in names(data)) {
  # Note the space before "agree" -- without it, it would match "disagree" as well!
  levels(data[,nn])[which(levels(data[,nn]) %>% endsWith(" agree"))] = "Agree"
  levels(data[,nn])[which(levels(data[,nn]) %>% endsWith("disagree"))] = "Disagree"
  if ( !all(levels(data[,nn]) %in% c("Agree", "Disagree")) ) {
    print(paste0(nn, ": not all levels converted"))
  }
}
data
#>          x        y        z
#> 1 Disagree    Agree Disagree
#> 2 Disagree Disagree    Agree
#> 3    Agree Disagree    Agree
#> 4    Agree    Agree Disagree
```